# Error when deploying application on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created an application using google app engine platform. Initially I tested the application locally using the GAE SDK with Eclipse and everything works fine. When I m trying to deploy it on Google`s server I get the following error:

" Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it. "

This is a very generic error. Is there a way to see the server`s log to get an idea of what might have went wrong?

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after looking around on GAE site , I found that you can view the server log in the following location:

Admin console -> "MyAppplication" -> Logs